# LINQ to SQL together with Entity Framework Database first

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

So I've had a problem with my .NET MVC application, when working with large amounts of data. Whenever I would load a lot of entities into the DOM and use the entity models, I experienced a lot of overhead, because of the realations loaded by the entity framework.

The way I solved this, was by using LINQ to SQL to query the database, and make the EF entity objects into DTOs. Here is a sample, of how I did:

```
        public IEnumerable<SIMCardDTO> GetSimCardsWithIssues(Guid customerId)
    {
        var result = from x in dbContext.SIMCard
                     where x.CustomerId == customerId
                     && x.SIMCardIssue.Any(y => y.IssueStatusId == 1)
                     || x.SIMCardIssue.Any(y => y.IssueStatusId == 3)
                     select new SIMCardDTO()
                     {
                         Id = x.Id,
                         ICCID = x.ICCID,
                         Name = x.Name,
                         City = x.City,
                         Housenumber = x.Housenumber,
                         GoogleCoordinates = x.GoogleCoordinates,
                         PhoneNumber = x.PhoneNumber,
                         StreetAddress = x.StreetAddress,
                         Zip = x.Zip,
                         Country = x.Country,
                         CreateDate = x.CreateDate,
                         DefaultPIN = x.DefaultPIN,
                         CustomerId = x.CustomerId,
                         IMEI = x.IMEI,
                         PUK1 = x.PUK1,
                         PUK2 = x.PUK2,
                         StatusId = x.StatusId,

                     };
        return result;
    }
```

(Notice that I'm doing this, because I have a lot of tabels that has references to the SIMCard entity, hence millions of objects are being loaded when I use the standard EF query). Here are the properties on the SIMCard:

```
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string ICCID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> DefaultPIN { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PUK1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PUK2 { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string Housenumber { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string GoogleCoordinates { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public System.Guid StatusId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SIMCardIssue> SIMCardIssue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SIMCardLog> SIMCardLog { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Task { get; set; }
```

As you can see, I'm not populating the navigation properties to my DTO, when querying the database.

My question to you guys is, if this is the right way to do it. I know that LINQ to SQL is not deprecated; but is there a smarter way to do this, using only the EF framework? I know that I have some more options if I use EF Code first; but this question is regarding database first (hence, my models are being regenerated every time I update the dbModel from the database).

How would you solve this?

Comment: So which part of this query does not work with EF?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work - it works fine. But I'm using LINQ to SQL, and I'm not quite sure that it's the right way to do it, given the fact that EF should be able to replace LINQ to SQL completely.

Comment: I don't see what you mean by overhead. the sql to linq query will give you a quiriable object after executing. This is basically a empty data skeleton with references. Once you request data from this reference the system will go to the database to get the actual data (note that doing this many times you will suffer performance issues). If however you want all the linked tables to be loaded you should use DataLoadOptions with your context. Then you can force the system to load the 'overhead' to save time later on.

Comment: Well from the code above there is no way to tell if you are using LINQ to SQL or EF. I don't understand what you are asking. You are talking about some overhead but you had not provided the code that produces the overhead. Relations in EF are eagerly loaded with Include if this is what causes the problem.

Comment: @NickOtten - It was actually the opposite problem i had. When using EF database first, all relations are being eagerly loaded, even when not using Include, and that's what caused the overhead I was referring to. As you can see, my DTO object doesn't have any navigation-properties, as apposed to my Entity Model, which has 5 IEnumerable navigation properties.

I guess what I'm really asking, is if the population of a List of DTO's, with a LINQ call like the above is a good way to do it or not.

Comment: @Stilgar - edited the original post with another example and the SIMCard Entity model

Comment: All relations are not meant to be eagerly loaded. You should try fixing your actual problem instead of trying hacks like using two different database frameworks.

Comment: I did not know, that they were not supposed to be eagerly loaded. I thought that was how EF Database first worked. Have you run into this issue before, or do you have any idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: EF should not eager load by default. You should provide a code sample where EF does that. Preferably self-contained sample. Check to see if you are not doing lazy-loading (best way is to force EF to log all queries in the output window in debug mode)  or doing some include somewhere or have something funny in the mapping.

Comment: I think I've made approximately 30 projects with EF database first; an they have all eagerly loaded all relations. I don't do anything special. For instance, I would get a list of SIMCards like this: public IEnumerable<SIMcard> GetSIMCards(Guid customerId){ return dbContext.SIMCard.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerID} - and it will always return SIMCard with all the relations. Keep in mind, that this is database first, where I create the dbModel from a SQL database, and not Code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, EF doesn't retrieves data from all related tables unless you explicitly say so.

I found few issues in your code -

### SIMCardIssue.Any should be only used once

```
var query = from x in dbContext.SIMCard
            where x.CustomerId == customerId
             && x.SIMCardIssue
               .Any(y => y.IssueStatusId == 1 || y.IssueStatusId == 3)
            select x;

return query.ToList();
```

Currently, you are retrieving all data; it makes your query very slow. In other words, You should only retrieve data that you want to display by using Skip and Take.

### Do not query straight to DTO

It is not good practice to query straight to DTO. Basically, you data layer should not need to know DTO.

Instead, you want to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map Domain Entity to DTO.

### Other thoughts

You want to SQL Server Profiles to see the query generated by EF.

Comment: If you read the comments, you would see the EF actually IS eager-loading all the realations in my case, by default. Normally, I would just query it like this:

    public IEnumerable<SIMCard> GetAllSimCards(Guid customerId){
       return dbContext.SIMCard.Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId);
    }

Comment: Your query is not correct; **SIMCard table** is joining twice with **SIMCardIssue**. Use **ToList** to see if it solves the problem. In addition, you want to use **SQL Server Profiler** to see the generated query.

Comment: The LINQ to SQL Query was not original problem; but thanks for pointing it out. I will accept your answer, as it provided some other information for me to look at; and I will start trying to find out, why EF with database first is eagerly loading all relations without me asking for it. Thanks for your contribution.